# How do I navigate to the field definition in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

For example:

```
private JMenuItem mntmSave;
```

In the Navigation menu item, I can open the declaration (Pressing F3). But, how do I navigate to the **definition**? How do I go to the specific line?

Answer (score 0):

Since `F3` does **not** work, I've managed to go to the definition pressing `CTRL + ALT + G`, having the variable selected (It searches for all occurences of the word within the workspace). It's not as specific, but it's better than scrolling.